# Can uglify-js remove the console.log statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs2

I'm using [uglify-js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to minify the source code. I want to remove the console.log statements of the original source code. Is it possible? Or is there any other compressor tool supports this?

I use the code as below in Node.js.

```
var uglify = require('uglify-js');
var originalSourceCode = 'var name = function(){var str = "test"; return str}; console.log("log data");';
var minifiedCode = uglify.minify(originalSourceCode, {
                fromString : true,
                mangle: {},
                warnings: true
            });
console.log(minifiedCode);
```

The output is:

```
$node m.js
{ code: 'var name=function(){var a="test";return a};console.log("log data");',
  map: 'null' }
```

In the minified code the console.log isn't removed.

Comment: I think there are several Grunt-plugins which can do that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the lastest uglify-js ( v2.4.3), a new compress option ‘pure_funcs’ is added. If I add the console.log functions to this array, it will be removed in the minified js file. The test code below shows how this option works. This is exactly what I want.

```
// file: m.js
var uglify = require('uglify-js');
var originalSourceCode = 'var name = function(){var str = "test"; return str}; console.log("log data" + name());';
var minifiedCode = uglify.minify(originalSourceCode, {
                fromString : true,
                mangle: {},
                warnings: true,
                compress:{
                    pure_funcs: [ 'console.log' ]
                }
            });
console.log(minifiedCode);

$node m.js
WARN: Dropping side-effect-free statement [?:1,53]
{ code: 'var name=function(){var n="test";return n};',
  map: 'null' }
```

Quotes from https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

> pure_funcs -- default null. You can pass an array of names and UglifyJS will assume that those functions do not produce side effects.
>   DANGER: will not check if the name is redefined in scope. An example
>   case here, for instance var q = Math.floor(a/b). If variable q is not
>   used elsewhere, UglifyJS will drop it, but will still keep the
>   Math.floor(a/b), not knowing what it does. You can pass pure_funcs: [
>   'Math.floor' ] to let it know that this function won't produce any
>   side effect, in which case the whole statement would get discarded.
>   The current implementation adds some overhead (compression will be
>   slower).

Answer (score 81):

There's also another option called drop_console which has been added recently (late 2013)

```
drop_console -- default false. Pass true to discard calls to console.* functions
```

This is added to the grunt init config like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    options: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: true // <-
      }
    },
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

As taken from the [grunt-contrib-uglify github documents](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/docs/uglify-examples.md)

Comment: That is awesome, but could you improve your answer by being more precise on where to add this in the Gruntfile.js?

Comment: See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/docs/uglify-examples.md add it to the compress parameter

Comment: Has now changed to dropConsole in camel case

Comment: This is not working!!! It says drop_console / dropConsole is not supported @benpalmer

Comment: Agreed, i get `Identifier 'drop_console' is not in camel case.` and an error if you make it `dropConsole`

Comment: I also tried it both ways, doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Works within grunt-require as well:
`requirejs: { options: { uglify2: { compress: { drop_console: true } } } }`

Answer (score 5):

for **-c** option, set **drop_console** to be **true**:

`uglifyjs app.js -m -c drop_console=true -o app.min.js`

Comment: How to add in Grunt.js ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Groundskeeper](https://github.com/Couto/groundskeeper) to do this though it will be a separate step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gulp, use 'gulp-strip-debug' to remove console, alert and debugger.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-debug