# How to pass options to UglifyJS through html-minifier on Windows command line?

Tags: json, node.js, cmd, escaping, minify

HTMLMinifier ([html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)) (3.5.14) for Node.js (v8.11.1), installed with `npm install html-minifier -g`, can be run via command line (**Windows CMD**), e.g. `html-minifier --help` produces the usage info (excerpts):

```
  Usage: html-minifier [options] [files...]

  Options:

    -V, --version                        output the version number
```

...

```
    --minify-js [value]                  Minify Javascript in script elements and on* attributes (uses uglify-js)
```

...

```
    -c --config-file <file>              Use config file
    --input-dir <dir>                    Specify an input directory
    --output-dir <dir>                   Specify an output directory
    --file-ext <text>                    Specify an extension to be read, ex: html
    -h, --help                           output usage information
```

The option `--minify-js [value]` relies on [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to "compress" the JavaScript embedded inside the HTML file(s) passed to `html-minifier`. UglifyJS can remove `console.log()` function calls ([Can uglify-js remove the console.log statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092466/can-uglify-js-remove-the-console-log-statements)) from the JavaScript, by enabling the [`drop_console`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options) option (also see `pure_funcs`).

But `--minify-js drop_console=true` does not have an effect, nor does something like `"uglify:{options:{compress:{drop_console:true}}}"` or `"compress:{pure_funcs:['console.log']}"`.

How can such an option be set, ideally via the html-minifier command line (alternatively by [config-file](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/sample-cli-config-file.conf), though it just sets `"minifyJS": true`)?

Comment: 2020: see https://github.com/DanielRuf/html-minifier-terser which is using https://github.com/terser/terser ("uglify-es is no longer maintained and uglify-js does not support ES6+. terser is a fork of uglify-es that mostly retains API and CLI compatibility with uglify-es and uglify-js@3")

Comment: `--decode-entity-characters` now is `--decode-entities` and `--html5` is "unknown", yet enabled by default.

Comment: Related: [How to pass terser options to html-minifier-terser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510989/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was very close.

I started digging through the code (installed in `%appdata%\npm\node_modules\html-minifier`) to see what happens with the options provided, i.e. adding debug output with `console.log(xyz);` (using an actual debugger probably would be a better idea).

So, here's my "trace":

- option: https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/cli.js#L118
- option handling: https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/cli.js#L144
- argument parsing using [`commander`][2]
- `createOptions()` https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/cli.js#L197

  - `options` then contains e.g. `minifyJS: 'compress:{pure_funcs:[\'console.log\']}',`
- passed on to `minify()` https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/src/htmlminifier.js#L806 which immediately runs
- `processOptions()` https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/src/htmlminifier.js#L616

where finally in line https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/src/htmlminifier.js#L667 `options.minifyJS` is handled, before it's run as `var result = UglifyJS.minify(code, minifyJS);` in https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/src/htmlminifier.js#L680.

But there our option string `compress:{pure_funcs:['console.log']}` gets cleaned because it's not yet an object, resulting in `{}`.

Or, in a different trial with a different string you may encounter the error `Could not parse JSON value '{compress:{pure_funcs:'console.log']}}'`

At least it gets that far! But why doesn't it work?

First, it's a good time to revisit the JSON spec: https://www.json.org/index.html

Second, see if the string could be parsed as valid JSON, e.g. with the  `JSON.parse()` demo at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Third, figure out how to get that string through the CMD as argument (escaping the double quotes).

Finally, make sure the data structure to configure UgliFyJS is correct. That's quite easy, since it's documented: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options-structure

And behold, simply escaping the double quotes with a backslash works for me:

`html-minfier ... --minify-js {\"compress\":{\"pure_funcs\":[\"console.log\"]}} ...`

and it properly shows up in the options as

```
...
{ compress:
   { pure_funcs: [ 'console.log' ],
...
```

Comment: This only works for logs which contain a string e.g `console.log("foo")`. Variables inside the `console.log` are not removed even though the `console.log` is removed. Example `console.log(arg)` becomes `arg`.

Comment: The options have changed with html-minifier-terser and terser and seem to break the code. `--minify-js {\"compress\":{\"drop_console\":\"true\"}} ^` seems to work, but have a look yourself at https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/57 (seems to contain useful tips at first glance).

Answer (score -2):

For ex. curl can read config from a file, like proxies, etc...
Many programs do so. git, maven, gradle.... No matter how and where you call them, they look for the config you or the system provides: first from the current directory, then from the user home and then the system /etc/...

If no batteries included with these node packages, they can only be used on separate html and js files.