# How to pass terser options to html-minifier-terser

Tags: minify, terser

How to pass terser options to html-minifier-terser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier-terser)?

The docs do not show any way to send it, only general options for html minify processing.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is coming late, but it might help someone with a similar question.

You can pass your Terser options through the `minifyJS` property. For example:

```js
htmlmin.minify(html, {
  minifyJS: {
    compress: {
      arrows: false,
    },
  },
})
```