# Deactivate Console.log and Logger or the Redux store in ReactJs production Mode

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, console.log

I am in the process of deploying my first ReacctJs application and  I will like to deactivate any  data from my application that shows in the console of the browser. This includes the redux store Logger, console.logs code etc.

I have tried out several approaches as I can find on google.

My store code looks as follows

```
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({
                        predicate: (getState, action) => process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
            });

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    )
);
```

I have installed the transform-remove-console package and created a .babelrc in my root folder with the following content

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

None of above codes removes things in the console. Please any ideas around this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: for console.logs, I'm terrible for removing them. If you're on mac or linux-based system, you could set up an alias like this `findlogs='grep resources/js/* -e '\''console\.log'\'' -rn'` - I always use Laravel/ReactJS hence the `resources/js/*` but you can change this to your path or just use `./*` to search in the current directory

Comment: Jamie, What if am switching back to development ??. it wont be efficient. Besides its actually a big project and i am not the only programmer there t

Answer (score 0):

If you use `terser-webpack-plugin` or `uglify-webpack-plugin` you may use `drop_console` option https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options

Some code sample from **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other options
  optimization: {
    minimize: !DEV,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          // ... other terser options
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },  
}
```

Some discussion here [Can uglify-js remove the console.log statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092466/can-uglify-js-remove-the-console-log-statements)